# Android 10 stacked USB permission when using intent-filter to start activity when USB attached

Tags: android-10.0, android-usb

**My setup**

- Pixel 3/Android 10 (but same problem on Samsung Galaxy S9/Android 9)
- App targets API 29 (Android 10)
- A USB device

On Android 10 there has been a change to the permission model, which means reading serial number for a USB device requires an explicit user permission, see: https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/data-identifiers#usb-serial-user-permission.

So when receiving an intent that a USB device is attached I automatically request a permission to read the serial number (results in a permission dialog: "Allow X to access Virtual COM Port ?").

[image: Permission dialog 1]

To also be able to launch the application when an appropriate USB device was attached it was previously possible to also do this (AndroidManifest.xml):

```
        <activity
                android:name="MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action
                        android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                        />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                    android:resource="@xml/my_device_filter"
                    />

        </activity>
```

... which results in a permission request dialog also when a new USB device is attached ("Open X to handle Com Port?").

[image: Permission dialog #2]

But, as previously mentioned, the application must also request permission for reading the serial number which results in a second permission dialog.

**These two dialogs are now stacked and if agreeing to the first dialog ("Open X to handle Virtual COM Port ?"), the second one ("Allow X to access COM Port ?") is dismissed automatically leading to broken functionality.**

**Any suggestions on how to handle these two permissions?**

Comment: A possible solution is to request multiple permissions at the same time (I have not yet had the time to verify this): https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en